# want to display data but first display the particular data start with 'k' like

Tags: sql

is it possible to display entire from table but starts with particular name like 'k'  ,i mean what are the names we have with k i want to display them first and after that i want to display remaining data
we can go with like,but,by that clause we will get only the data with particular name.but i want to display remaining data also..

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `case`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when name like 'k%' then 1 else 2 end);
```

Comment: if i do like this then i will get the only names with 'k' ,but, i would like to get all name but first prior to the 'k'

Comment: @Mani . . . This answers your question:  'names we have with k i want to display them first and after that i want to display remaining data ".  If you have another question, ask it as another question.

Comment: @Mani this will display all the data, it just sorted them displaying the names with k% first then the other data.

Comment: Oho..Fine Thank you       @Gordon and Ferdinand